# C# Usercontrol's memory leak

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, user-controls

I have some heavy memory leak in my application.

This is the form that loads a lot of stuff in memory, it is a form with 3 `FlowLayoutPanel`. Every panel has a lot of a `UserControl` I've created, they're just a picturebox with a label. Let's call the form `ColorViewer`:[image]

Whenever I open this form it takes close to 300-400 MB of memory and it doesn't seems to release it.

This a graph of the memory usage:
[image]

As you can the first time I open `ColorViewer` it loads everything in memory (close to 400mb) and then it never dispose. After that, every time I open `ColorViewer` it is disposed correctly.

This is the code I use to load my form, I guess the memory leak is in the loading of the img. As of right now I use the default `Dispose()`:

```
//Loading of one of the three panel in the form,called 3 time when the form is opened:
                colorsViewerPanel.AddColorRange(colours.ConvertAll(x => new ColorBox(x.path_img, x.id,true)));

//Function that loads my UserControl into the panel
      public void AddColorRange(List<ColorBox> cBoxList)
        {
             flowLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();

             foreach (var cBox in cBoxList)
                  flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cBox);

             flowLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout();
        }

//This is the ColorBox usercontrol's class

public string pathImg{ get; set; }
public int id{ get; set; }
public bool selected{ get; set; }

//This is the constructor for the UserControl
public ColorBox(string pathImage,int idImage,bool sel = true)
  {
        InitializeComponent();
        pathImg = pathImage;
        id = idImage;
        selected = sel;

        //Load img
        if (File.Exists(pathImg))
        {
          Image img;
          using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(pathImg))
          {
                img = new Bitmap(pathImg);
          }

          panelColor.BackgroundImage = img;
          panelColor.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
          labelColor.Text = id;
        }
  }
```

Is this normal ?

Comment: Memory isn't automatically released back to the system.  It's hard to allocate, so the CLR holds onto it as long as possible.  If you really are worried about a memory leak, there are tools out there to diagnose this (and search engines where you can find them).

Comment: And how can we help you if you don't share a single line of code?

Comment: Manually call GC to see if it gets released?

Comment: Your statement "After that, every time I open ColorViewer it is disposed correctly" makes no sense.  Either it's disposing, or it isn't.  Unless you're doing something rather bizarre and _only the first time_.

Comment: @DonBoitnott The load is the same every time, but the first time is is cleared only when I close the program or I force the GC collector to run via dotMemory. I added the code where the memory leak happens.

Comment: @DonBoitnott You know what do you know, swag bello gu [STAI LI A NON RISPONDERE!]

Comment: It seems that bitmap created in "img = new Bitmap(pathImg);" is never disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not disposing anything useful here:

```
 Image img;
 using (var bmpTemp = new Bitmap(pathImg))
 {
    img = new Bitmap(pathImg);
 }
```

you are just creating an instance (bmpTemp) of the Bitmap class (that is later going to be disposed because of the using statement) and then assigning a new istance of the same class to another variable (img, the one you are effectively using). Anyway, even if you correct this, it will not work for your purposes, because there's no meaning in disposing the Image you are actually showing in a PictureBox (and this will also lead to an exception later on).

As you can read here, **it is necessary to call Dispose on an Image object to effectively get rid of its presence in memory**, keeping in mind that Bitmap is a wrapper around an unmanaged GDI+ bitmap (and probably requires special needs to get disposed even when wrapped):

[Image.Dispose()](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.dispose?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Image_Dispose)

That said, given the code you provided and to cut the problem at the root, I guess I would probably implement the IDisposable interface on the ColorBox control to make sure the Dispose method of the Image instance is always called when the control is disposed:

[Implement IDisposable correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1063?view=vs-2019)

In your specific case, I would consider the Image/Bitmap object as a fully unmanaged object and I would free it in the "free native resources if there are any" section of the Dispose method so that, if someone is using your control without disposing it, the call to the finalizer is going to happen anyway if the object is eligible for finalization. Something like this:

```
 // The bulk of the clean-up code is implemented in Dispose(bool)
 protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
 {
    if (isDisposed) return;

    if (disposing)
    {
        // free managed resources
        managedResource.Dispose();
    }

    // free native resources if there are any.
    if (!(img is null))
    {
       // Our Image.
       img.Dispose();
    }
    isDisposed = true;
 }
```